# C programming with iconv lib in Linux

Tags: c, linux, iconv

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iconv.h>

int main()
{
    char input[BUFSIZ];
    char output[BUFSIZ];
    size_t insize = BUFSIZ;
    size_t outsize = BUFSIZ;

    char **inp = (char **)input;
    char **outp = (char **)output;

    iconv_t cd = iconv_open("gb2312", "utf-8");

    memset(input, '\0', sizeof(input));
    memset(output, '\0', sizeof(output));
//  freopen("input", "r", stdin);
    scanf("%s", input);
    insize = strlen(input);

    iconv(cd, inp, &insize, outp, &outsize);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    iconv_close(cd);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it, I got this message:

**a.out:**
**gconv.c:75: __gconv: Assertion**
**`outbuf != ((void *)0) && *outbuf != ((void *)0)' failed.**
**已放弃**

I can't found any problem and I feel helpless~ I'm not good at english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fourth argument looks wrong. The casting is a good clue that something weird/confused is going on.

You need to pass it a pointer to a pointer, you are passing it a pointer to a character array *cast to a pointer to a pointer*. That's not the same thing.

You probably need:

```
char output[BUFSIZ], *outp = output;
```

Then call it with `&outp` as the fourth argument.

Comment: @thlgood Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it's the right one.